Google SERP picks unrelavant image from related products
I have a website url
https://www.sensoware.com/motorized-ball-valve-brass/
for "motorized valves" keyword in google search
it shows the above in SERP
https://www.sensoware.com/motorized-ball-valve-brass/
acutally i have a related products section where i keep diferent valves picture. Actually the SERP shows Motorized butterfly valve image.
This makes the search visitor to be misguided when seeing the title and image. So is there any solution for the same.
Or should i need to keep the related products images Alt text something like "not relevant keywords" like mfv-bfl-val codes

You're using "motorized" in the alt text for the butterfly valve and "electric" in the alt text for the ball valve, so Google is picking up on more words relevant to the search at the beginning of the butterfly valve's alt text and deciding it's more relevant.
Try wrapping your related products in an <aside> rather than a <div> to make it more clear that it's not part of the main product.
